# Is there a way to add daily events to the default CalenderDatePicker object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, android-widget

I wanted to implement a calendar page in my app, wherein, I can let user to pick a date from a calendar and also let him see the events overview if any, on any given day of that month by using a small dot on the day number. I just want to know weather we can do that on a flutter default 'CalenderDatePicker' object or not. I don't want to use any third party packages, if possible.

Till now I implemented a 'CalenderDatePicker' object but I'm unable to figure out a way to add events overview to it.